# How to fix "No Route Matches" error with Rails i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now I'm translating my rails app with rails i18n.

But path tests already passed have shown errors because i18n changed routes.
The error below is one of the errors.

I think my app is working well, so my tests have something wrong though.
I wanna know how to fix it.

Any solutions?

### Error

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 3.4624758772552013]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (3.46s)
　　ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
　　ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :locale=>#<User id: 762146111, 
　　　name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2022-11-09 09:53:30", updated_at: "2022-11-09 09:53:30",
　　　password_digest: "$2a$04$r.WTFttwDcJsuUdBSHQDi.IvFzECkpL37SEdlAKzpdX...", remember_digest: nil,
　　　admin: true, activation_digest: nil, activated: true, activated_at: "2022-11-09 09:53:30", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil>},
　　　missing required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]
    　　 test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

### Codes relating to the error

1. routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en | ja/ do
    root 'static_pages#home'

    get     '/:locale' => 'static_pages#home'
    get     '/help',        to: 'static_pages#help'
    get     '/about',       to: 'static_pages#about'
    get     '/contact',     to: 'static_pages#contact'
    get     '/search',      to: 'movies#search'
    get     '/show',        to: 'movies#show'
    get     '/signup',      to: 'users#new'
    post    '/signup',      to: 'users#create'
    post    '/guest_login', to: 'guest_sessions#create'
    get     '/login',       to: 'sessions#new'
    post    '/login',       to: 'sessions#create'
    delete  '/logout',      to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users do
      member do
        get :following, :followers
      end
    end
    resources :movies
    resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
    resources :resend_activations,  only: [:new, :create]
    resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :comments do
      resource :comments,           only: [:create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      resource :favorites,          only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
    resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

2. application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Moviest
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my/locales/*.{rb,yml}')]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
    
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true

    config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  end
end
```

3. application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_request
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_request
    Thread.current[:request] = request
  end
  
  around_action :switch_locale

  def switch_locale(&action)
    locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end
 
  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
  
  〜〜〜〜

end
```

4. users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  
  def setup
    @user       = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end
  
  ~

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)　　　　　#error point
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
  
  ~

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error with defining locale on a test file and calling it when @user was called.
The error occurred because test-driven development was used for the test based on Rails Tutorial, which means that locale is need to be defined on a test file.
Anyway, thank you.